# Extract URL from a string of html elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, ecmascript-6

I have this **string** of elements in data:

```
"<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="pr" content="no-cache">
   <title>Redirection to 20331...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <script> language="javascript">
    location = 'https://cloud.analytics.google.com:92/force/ForceRedirect/Redirect.do?id=20331';
   </script>
  </body>
</html>"
```

I need to extract the URL in this string.

Current implementation:

```
data.split(' ')[6].split("'")[0];
```

This ***workaround*** returns me the link and works fine but because I am basically hardcoding the position of the URL I need a method to handle this. Appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex! For example, I saw in the HTML that the URL can appear in the format `location = '...'` so we can match that with regex:

```
const match = data.match(/location = '(.+)'/);
const url = match ? match[1] : null;
```

Google "regex", there's a ton of resources online for learning regex. Here's the reference for the `match` function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match